# K-means to cluster texts, scaling

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, python, k-means, optimal-scaling

I want to cluster a folder of texts. I created a data file where for each text, I write whether a certain word appears in it or not. I want to cluster according to this.

**So my matrix is globally only 0 and 1, where each column indicates whether that specific word appears in one text or not.**

My question is the following :

> Should I scale my data ?

I have to admit having no clue, because, while I agree that some words will appear more then others (like : "and" will certainly appear everywhere, whereas "ADN" perhaps less in maths-related texts), scaling is only looking row by row, I.E. text by text, right ? So he can't really scale 0 and 1...

**And in any case, for k-means, scaling is so important that it can make your results totally false. So what do you think?**

Any feedback is welcome !

cheers.

Comment: I know this isn't the question, but I think Kmeans will likely not work very well because of the high dimensional of the problem.  Methods like Latent Dirichlet Allocation are usually used for these sorts of problems and may be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

In text mining, short, highly frequent words like "a", "of", "the", "an", "and", are dropped from the document-word frequency table.  For the other more common words, you have to sum the number of times words appear in each document, since if e.g. "bicycle" is used more frequently in one document than another, it will suggest the document may be about cycling.  Whereas if many documents have one occurrence of "bicycle", your method of only setting to 1 if present won't detect the document on bicycles (which may have 20 counts of the word "bicycle").

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that the data in the matrix only acts the presence or not of one of the $1433$ choosen words. I don't know how many time a word appears in the document. That's my problem, because I would have a matrix with a whole range of numbers I would scale it, but here I only have $0$ and $1$

Comment: you have to obtain word frequencies, i.e., number of times each word appears in each document divided by #words in each document.

Comment: but I don't have that information ??? I only have presence or not. For instance : 

"I love big brown dogs and small brown horses" would give : dogs = 1, small = 1, brown = 1, cat = 0

Comment: yes you do have that information, since you have the "texts".  All you need to do is determine the "word frequency" in each text.  Then construct a table of word frequencies vs document.