# Can one do one-hot encoding with Count Vectorizer?

Tags: machine-learning, python, categorical-encoding

I am new to machine learning. I am stuck with a doubt about whether we could do one-hot encoding using bag of words (e.g. [scikit-learn's `CountVectorizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html))?

Comment: what is count vectorizer, and what is the application -- perhaps text mining?  for "words," do you mean word-document frequencies?

Comment: @NXGLogic count vectorizer is a function of scikit learn library in python. It is used in text mining to from bag of words representation of vectors from a corpus of words.

Comment: see this answer (https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/442663/32398), where one-hot coding was proposed for text mining.  You need word frequencies in each document (i.e., # times each word appeared), and not 0,1 coding for whether a word was present or not (y/n).

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you can! However, their primary purposes are different. CountVectorizer is generally used for featurization of text data whereas OneHotEncoder is only used for featurization of categorical variables.

Comment: Sorry—how do you propose to make the data one-hot with scikit-learn's `CountVectorizer`? In the obvious way of using it, the vector representation would be multi-hot.

Comment: CountVectorizer creates a new feature for each unique word in the document, or in this case, a new feature for each unique categorical variable. However, this may not work if the categorical variables have spaces within their names (it would be multi-hot then as you pointed out)

Comment: There's one _feature_ per token in the training corpus, but the representation of a _document_ is a fixed-length, multi-hot vector. CountVectorizer is used to create a bag (or set, if `binary=True`) of words representation of a document.